# Run Shell command in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell, command, execute

I can run some Shell Linux commands in Perl (for example create a folder). But I can't execute followed command:

```
echo 'mypassword' | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output outfile --decrypt inputfile
```

I add this command in .sh file and could execute in Shell fine. but when I call .sh file, Perl couldn't run it. I used `open3`, `system`, `open` commands to run. I could run other .sh file, but not for this command.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using backquote/backtick, seems to work fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

`echo 'mypassword' | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --output outfile --decrypt inputfile`
```

P.S. I would better use some cpan module like [GPG](http://search.cpan.org/~miles/GPG-0.06/GPG.pm).