# perl shell command variable error

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I am trying following code in one of my perl script and getting error, how do i execute following shell command and store in variable

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $p = $( PROCS=`echo /proc/[0-9]*|wc -w|tr -d ' '`; read L1 L2 L3 DUMMY < /proc/loadavg ; echo ${L1}:${L2}:${L3}:${PROCS} );
print $p;
```

Error:

```
./foo.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at /tmp/foo.pl line 3, near "$( PROCS"
        (Missing operator before PROCS?)
syntax error at /tmp/foo.pl line 3, near "$( PROCS"
Unterminated <> operator at /tmp/foo.pl line 3.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: probably the `$` before the `(`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Shell command in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164179/run-shell-command-in-perl). Tip: sometimes it's easier to look up how to do something than debugging errors you get trying to do it. In this case, you've invented some `$(syntax)` that perl doesn't support.

Comment: @thatotherguy i tried `ehco` also but didn't work :(

Comment: what output are you after? You almost never need `echo` in perl.

Comment: Why `down` vote this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `print`ing a shell command in your Perl script won't actually execute it. You have to tell Perl that it's an external command, which you can do with `system`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = q{
    PROCS=`echo /proc/[0-9]*|wc -w|tr -d ' '`;
    read L1 L2 L3 DUMMY < /proc/loadavg;
    echo ${L1}:${L2}:${L3}:${PROCS}
};
system($command);
```

(Note that you should put `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of *every* Perl script you write.)

However, it's generally better to use native Perl functionality instead of `system`. All you're doing is reading from files, which Perl is perfectly capable of doing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @procs = glob '/proc/[0-9]*';

my $file = '/proc/loadavg';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Failed to open '$file': $!";

my $load = <$fh>;

say(join ':', (split ' ', $load)[0..2], scalar @procs);
```

Even better might be to use the [`Proc::ProcessTable`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::ProcessTable) module, which provides a consistent interface to the `/proc` filesystem across different flavors of *nix. It got some bad reviews early on but is supposedly getting bugfixes now; I haven't used it myself but you might take a look.

Comment: Great!! you got it right, thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
my $p = $( PROCS=`echo /proc/[0-9]*|wc -w|tr -d ' '`; read L1 L2 L3 DUMMY < /proc/loadavg ; echo ${L1}:${L2}:${L3}:${PROCS} );
```

Isn't perl. It's how you'd execute a command in `bash`.

To run a command in perl you can:

- use `system`.
- put your command in backticks
- `qx` (quote-execute): http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

However, you're enumerating a directory there, wordcounting, tr-ing and reading. So you don't actually need to do all that using a shell command. And indeed, I'd discourage you from doing so, because that's just a way to make a mess with no productive benefit.

Looks like what you're after as an end result is the 3 load average samples and a count of number of processes. Is that right?

In which case:

```
my $proc_count = scalar ( () = glob ( "/proc/[0-9]*" ));
open ( my $la, "<", "/proc/loadavg" ) or warn $!; 
print join ( ":", split ( /\s+/, <$la> ), $proc_count ),"\n";
```

Something like that, anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes. Good point. I've used globs in while loops before, for exactly that reason. Amended.